# What is an equivalent of Windows' Autoruns for Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, software-rec

Is there any graphical software for Linux with similar functionality as Sysinternals has for Windows?

[image: sysinternals]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and specify _exactly_ what functionality you need. That is a screenshot of a very complicated GUI with loads of options.

Comment: note that in linux there are more then just one desktop, so at which desktop you refer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows is more or less standardized by Microsoft, so the Autoruns utility is just one for all versions of Windows. Linux on the desktop is not standardized at all and no such tool exists.

- For system services you have `Systemd`, `SysVinit`, `upstart` and [many others](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Comparison_of_init_systems) all with their own distinct configurations.
- For X.org you have `/etc/X11/xinit/*` - for Wayland you've got none of that.
- For a graphical session you may have `~/.config/autostart` but various desktop (KDE, Gnome, XFCE, Enlightenment) environments have their own ways of starting applications.

It's near impossible to write such an utility for all distros and then you have to constantly maintain it.